# Angular Observable filtering doesn't working

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have an Observable array and I want to filter it by some properties. However, the filtering doesn't working.
I tried debugging the code but it's like it doesn't go into the `pipe(map(...` section.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.bookService.getBooks().subscribe(res => {
      this.store.dispatch(listBooks({ books: res }));
    });

    this.filterForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: [""],
      author: [""],
      release_year: [""]
    });

    this.filterForm.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
      this.books$.pipe(map(books => 
        books.filter(b => {
          return b.name.startsWith(val.name) &&
          b.author.startsWith(val.author) &&
          b.release_year.startsWith(val.release_year)
        })
      ))
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't look like a complete example - e.g. what is `this.book$` ?

Additionally your `pipe()` doesn't seem to end with a `subscribe()` - and so will not ever do anything

Comment: Thank you, ```subscribe()``` solved my problem.

Comment: Glad to help. Please just accept this as answer - thank you.

Answer (score 1):

this line of your code never execute
this.books$.pipe(
because you dont subscribe it.any observable need to subscribe to execute.

it is better change your code like below code:

```
  this.filterForm.valueChanges
  .pipe(
   withLatestFrom(this.books$),
   map(([val,books])>
      books.filter(b => {
        return b.name.startsWith(val.name) &&
        b.author.startsWith(val.author) &&
        b.release_year.startsWith(val.release_year)
      })
   ))
   .subscribe(books => {
    this.books=books;        
   ))
```